# How To Make this Code work

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader(fs);
   string linevalue = "";
   ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
   while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       items.Add(linevalue);
   }
   filereader.Close();
   items.Sort();
   IEnumerator myEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
   while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       Console.WriteLine(myEnumerator.Current);
   }
}
```

---

My program needs trouble shooting. This program, i actually got it from SO by a brilliant guy but i am not able to trace back. I don't know what's wrong. I want everything that is stored in my text file to be stored and displayed through the array list. Any help would be appreciated.

It get's displayed but incorrectly.
My Text File has got the following details

```
       Names            Date           Time
       Leon             13/10/2013     10:00AM
       Jyothika         18/10/2013     12:18PM
       Angelina         21/09/2000     01:45AM
```

Instead of displaying it in the same manner, it displays like

```
       Angelina          21/09/2000     01:45AM
       Names             Dates          Time
       Leon              13/10/2013     10:00AM
       Jyothika          18/10/2013     12:18PM
```

Comment: you are reading linevalue twice before adding to items

Comment: _"i actually got it from SO by a brilliant guy"_ - please. Anyway did you try setting a breakpoint and walking through your code to see what it does?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your reading `linevalue` again before adding to items:

You can do it in an easier way:

```
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Scheduler.txt").ToList();
  lines.Sort();
  foreach(var line in lines)  Console.WriteLine( line );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //linevalue = filereader.ReadLine();
    items.Add(linevalue);
}
```

An easier way:

```
// store your items
ArrayList items =
    new ArrayList(File.ReadAllLines("Scheduler.txt").ToArray());
// output them, eventually
items.ToArray().ToList().ForEach(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
});
```

Comment: ArrayList? seriously? So last decade :)

Comment: No, you aren't aligning, because `ToList()` is LINQ

Comment: In the second part, you are correct. But if the `items` object should be passed to some ancient method, then you may say I covered the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader(fs);
   string linevalue = "";
   ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
   while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       //linevalue = filereader.ReadLine();
       items.Add(linevalue);
   }
   filereader.Close();
   items.Sort();
   IEnumerator myEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
   while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       Console.WriteLine(myEnumerator.Current);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not generating anything on my console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Title Line is a line, so it gets sorted with the other lines. There are various ways to solve this problem... Read the Title Line separately in another variable and not adding to the `ArrayList`, remove from the `ArrayList` the first row before sorting, sort only the rows after the first... I chose the last one and wrote some variants that show how the code could be written.

First level, not sort the first row, and using the `using` keyword, instead of manually closing the files.

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string linevalue = string.Empty;

    while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        items.Add(linevalue);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(items[0]);
items.Sort(1, items.Count - 1, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);

IEnumerator myEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
myEnumerator.MoveNext(); // skip the first row

while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(myEnumerator.Current);
}
```

Second level, please forget of `ArrayList`... It's a child of a pre-literate world... I hope one day we will be able to forget that world. And using the `GetEnumerator` manually? There is the `foreach` (or the `for`, being the collection an `ArrayList`/`List<string>` for these things. The `for` is better, because we must skip the first row.

```
var items = new List<string>();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string linevalue = string.Empty;

    while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        items.Add(linevalue);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(items[0]);
items.Sort(1, items.Count - 1, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);

for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
}
```

Then we could remove the `FileStream`, because the `StreamReader` has a good-enough constructor...

```
using (StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader("Scheduler.txt"))
```

Or we could directly use the `File.ReadAllLines` that returns an array of `string[]`.

```
string[] items = File.ReadAllLines("Scheduler.txt");

Console.WriteLine(items[0]);
Array.Sort(items, 1, items.Length - 1, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);

for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
}
```

or, instead of the `for`, we could use a little LINQ:

```
foreach (string item in items.Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

and use the `Skip` method to skip the first row (these lines of LINQ are compatible with all the versions that don't use `ArrayList`)